# WordPress (3.9.1) MultiSite Permissions. Is chown the answer?

Tags: php, multisite, uploads, apache

**The situation:**

I'm working on a WordPress MultiSite for a charity. They have a Dedicated Apache Server running multiple Domain Names (Accounts).

I preparation for Development & Production, which will occur on the same Domain Name within that Dedicated Server, I made a few test installations on a separate Shared Hosting Environment using different Domain Names. No problems whatsoever during these tests on Shared Hosting.

I understand the reason why I'm getting the following errors, and I am happy, during Development (which is Password Protected) to switch *CHMOD* File Permissions of /uploads/ & uploads/site/2 to 0777 in order to be able to Upload from within WordPress, but obviously I'd prefer not to use 0777 for the Production Release.

**A question of Hosting Support Time**

The charity I work for have a fixed and pre-agreed support contract, which doesn't, at the moment, include Server Support for WordPress. So I want to make sure I approach the Hosting Provider (a Web Design Agency / Hosting Reseller) with a set of definite instruction on how to solve the Server Side issue.

Basically, I don't want to run the risk of a seemingly simple Server Support request turning into a lengthy discussion on solutions - I would prefer to provide them with a definitive guide to solving the Server Side / Permissions issue, which is what they'd also prefer, actually.

What specific instructions should I give to the Hosting Provider in order to solve the Errors that I've outlined below?

**The Problem:**

1. Error:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.

And for the 2nd Site...,

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/sites/2.

And for Plugins installation...,

> Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.

**My Technical Predicament:**

From what I've researched, possible solution:

- **chown?**

> you need to chown your installation to the php user too. i.e. if your user is www-data and they're a member of www-data you'd do $chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sites/ - [Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-multisite-is-unable-to-upload-media-files-because-it-does-not-have-the-necessary-permissions)

- ***WP_TEMP_DIR*?**

> I'd try adding the following to your wp-config.php file to force it to
>   use the wp-content directory *define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH .
>   'wp-content/');* - [Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-installupdate-plugins-since-upgrade-to-32#post-2214887)

**Point #1** - I have no experience of dealing with chown, so I'm not sure if this would be the correct guidance I should provide to the Hosting Provider.

**Point #2** - from what I've read, it is NOT a good idea to define Constants for /temp/ Directories in this way. And, actually - I would prefer not to extend the wp-config.php as a fix.

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a section on WordPress file permissions in the Codex article on [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#file-permissions). The article doesn't talk much about Multisite, but it should be treated similarly to the rest of `wp-content` -- ie, the server process needs to be able to write to it.

I'd steer clear of doing `chown www-data:www-data [/path/]wp-content/uploads/sites` -- you should be able to achieve the same effect by using `chgrp`, which changes the group permissions on the files & directories. Something like

```
chgrp -R www-data wp-content/uploads/sites
chmod -R g+w wp-content/uploads/sites
```

might be what you're looking for.

The first line changes the group that owns the directory in question (and the `-R` applies it to all files and subdirectories too). The second line changes the "mode" (the permissions) so that the group can write files and directories. (`-R` again does it recursively; `g+w` is the group-writeable part.)

*Caveat* -- every setup is different; you should probably double-check with your hosting company if this setup is kosher.

Comment: I'll use this as one likely possible solution if I may. FYI, I followed the instruction provided here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108990/52557 -- since currently I also need to  provide FTP to Upload Plugins - the Output: '_cant write file_'. Seems related.

Comment: Update: The reason was due to how Plesk creates web users accounts and the default group it assigns it to. Though I didn't enquire any further, apparently the ISP installed an apache module to cater for the folder permissions requirement. Seems like they'll need to add this module to each new Domain/Account created on the Dedicated Server, since we created a new Domain today, and saw the same permissions related issue. Certainly, "Plesk + WP Permissions" is a more relevant search engine keyword combination hereon.